# How to make this function apply on each matched element in the following JsonML?

Tags: javascript, json, markdown

I have the following JsonML generated via [markdown-js](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js):

```
[ 'markdown',
  [ 'para', 'This is a paragraph.' ],
  [ 'para', 'Another paragraph' ] ]
```

What I'm trying to do is to add the class `noind` to each paragraph tag. Full code:

```
var text = "This is a paragraph.\n\n" +
  "Another paragraph"

// parse the markdown into a tree and grab the link references
var tree = md.parse(text)
var refs = tree[1]

//console.log(refs)

;(function update_paras(jsonml) {

  if (jsonml[1][0] === 'para') {
    var par = jsonml[1]
    par.splice(1,0,{'class': 'noind'})
  }

})(tree)

var html = md.renderJsonML(md.toHTMLTree(tree))
console.log(html)
```

Right now the class is only added to the first paragraph:

```
<p class="noind">This is a paragraph.</p>

<p>Another paragraph</p>
```

How can I do it so that the class is add to all of them?

**EDIT:**

In their example on [Gitub](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js) they did something like this (with link_refs):

```
if (jsonml[0] === "link_ref") {
  // some code
} else if (Array.isArray(jsonml[1])) {
  jsonml[1].forEach(find_link_refs)
} else if (Array.isArray(jsonml[2])) {
  jsonml[2].forEach(find_link_refs)
}
```

I don't quite understand the code, though. And when I tried the same, it didn't work (still only the first paragraph got the class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an expert, but this looks better formatted as an answer than as a comment.

Have you tried creating a loop that goes through all the elements in the jsonml array (right now it's only reading the first one)? Something like this:

```
;(function update_paras(jsonml) {

    for (x = 1; x < jsonml.length; x++) {
        if (jsonml[x][0] === 'para') {
            var par = jsonml[x]
            par.splice(1,0,{'class': 'noind'})
        }
    }

})(tree)
```

Comment: hey, it worked. I'll select your answer if there isn't another better. What's the difference between the `else if` example? Do you know why they did it that way?

Comment: The example that you put from Github is not a loop, it only looks the first 2 elements (and only if they are link_refs) and then loops through them. It works for code like `[ "link_ref", [ [ "xxx", "yyy"], [ "xxx", "yyy" ], ... ], ... ]`, (notice how the second element is an array of arrays), but your code is `[ "markdown", [ "xxx", "yyy"], [ "xxx", "yyy"], ... ]` (your second element is an array of values)

Comment: I feel like the explanation I gave you is more confusing than what it should be... the idea is that your markdown is made with arrays of key/value pairs, and the github code works only for arrays of arrays.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I think I got it. I just didn't know why they didn't use a `for loop`.